# How can I launch java code from InstallAnywhere?

Tags: java, installanywhere

I want to launch static function from jar file and recieve its return value during install time. Is there some other way, rather then executing java.exe?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Do you mean at installer build time or when the installer runs?  Do you NEED to launch a separate JVM ... or could you run the code in the JVM that is running (or building) the installer?  (And if you need to, why?)

Comment: Why do you rank down the question?

Comment: From the documentation it appears that IA supports groovy. So in theory you can execute Java methods from groovy, could you not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really fail to understand the reason for downvotes...

You can run custom code during the installation by extending from CustomCodeAction of InstallAnywhere. All you need to do is to override the `install` and `uninstall` methods of the base class. Please find the snippet of the sample code below.

```
public class MyCustomCodeAction extends CustomCodeAction {
    public void install(InstallerProxy proxy) throws InstallException {
        // call the static function of your jar here
    }

    public void uninstall(UninstallerProxy Uproxy) throws InstallException {
        // you can do something here if you need (not must)
    }
}
```

Good luck!